# Control output from makefile

Tags: c, makefile

I'm trying to write a makefile to replace one of the scripts used in building a fairly large application.

The current script compiles one file at a time, and the primary reason for using make is to parallelise the build process.  Using `make -j 16` I currently get a factor of 4 speedup on our office server.

But what I've lost is some readability of the output.  The compilation program for a file bundles up a few bits and pieces of work, including running custom pre-compilers, and running the `gcc` command.  Each of these steps outputs some information, and I would prefer it to buffer the output from the command, and then show the whole lot in one go.

Is it possible to make `make` do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple way to accomplish this is to send all the log output a to log directory with each file named, say:

```
log_file_20131104_12013478_b.txt  // log_file_<date>_<time>_<sequence letter>.txt
```

and then simply `cat` them all together as your last make job in the dependency chain:

```
cat log_dir/log_file_20131104_12013478_*.txt > log_file_20131104_12013478.txt
```

Comment: I can't rely on GNU make, let alone version 4, as I have to make this work on commercial UNIX also, so I may have to go with this sort of solution.

Comment: How hard is it to download and compile GNU make there?

Answer (score 3):

If you upgrade to GNU make 4.0, then you can use the built-in output synchronization feature to get what you want.

If you don't want to upgrade, then you'll have to modify each of your recipes to be wrapped with a small program that manages the output.  Or you can set the `SHELL` variable to something that does it for you.  Searching the internet should give you some examples.

Comment: Aha then it's not just me that wants this feature!

Answer (score 0):

With [makepp](http://makepp.sourceforge.net/) this is the default behaviour as soon as you use -j.  All the individual outputs (and entering dir messages) get collected and are output together as soon as the command terminates.